Prisma Error: 'empty database name not allowed' while creating user
I'm encountering an error while trying to create a user in my Node.js application using Prisma and MongoDB Atlas. Here's the specific error message:
Error creating user
Steps to Reproduce:
I send a POST request to the /api/register endpoint with user data in the body (username, email, password).
The application attempts to create the user using Prisma.
Relevant Code Snippet (auth.controller.js):
export const register = async (req, res) => {
  // ... (code to extract user data)

  try {
    const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        username,
        email,
        password: hashedPassword,
      },
    });
    // ... (success handling)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error creating user" });
  }
};

I've verified that the .env file contains the correct database name in the connection URL.
I've examined the console logs for any additional error messages related to Prisma or database connection.
I've double-checked my Postman request to ensure it sends the correct data for user creation.
I've restarted the application server after making changes.
 "dependencies": { "@prisma/client": "^5.15.0", "bcrypt": "^5.1.1", "express": "^4.19.2", "prisma": "^5.15.0" }

What did console.error(error); output in the console then?

Wasted 20 min on this. in your env file, make sure to add the database name before the ?. like mongodb.net/YOUR_DB_NAME?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName . Not sure why but the mongodb/Atlast provided connection string doesnt have that part when you copy.
